# Xcode image scaling for 2x,3x not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I have an image called shareIdea. I created @2x, @3x and named them shareIdea@2x and shareIdea@3x. I have added them to xcode as you can see in the image here:

[image: Here]

However when I compile and run. The images used along my toolbar are still the 22px. So I'm unsure what to do or how to fix it.

Comment: What are the pixel sizes of the 2x and 3x images? How do you know the app is using the 22px image? You do know that 3x images are only used on the iPhone 6+, right?

Comment: @rmaddy yep I do. Image sizes are 22px, 44px, 66px for a toolbar custom image

Comment: how are you checking the size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

In each device you have a image proportion that the SO will request, they will use the "maximum" available for each one.

- 4, 4s, 5, 5s and6 (Max @2x)
- 6 plus (Max @3x )